# How to create an IPFS compatible multihash

Tags: ipfs

I'm trying to create an IPFS compatible mutihash but it is not matching.  I am asking here because I have not yet found an example that takes this from hashing to the end result.

```
echo -n multihash > multihash.txt


ipfs add multihash.txt
added QmZLXzjiZU39eN8QirMZ2CGXjMLiuEkQriRu7a7FeSB4fg multihash.txt


sha256sum multihash.txt
9cbc07c3f991725836a3aa2a581ca2029198aa420b9d99bc0e131d9f3e2cbe47  multihash.txt

node

> var bs58=require('bs58')
bs58.encode(new Buffer('9cbc07c3f991725836a3aa2a581ca2029198aa420b9d99bc0e131d9f3e2cbe47','hex'))
'BYptxaTgpcBrqZx9tghNCWFfUuYBcGfLydEvDjXqBV7k'

> var mh=require('multihashes')
mh.toB58String(mh.encode(new Buffer('9cbc07c3f991725836a3aa2a581ca2029198aa420b9d99bc0e131d9f3e2cbe47','hex'), 'sha2-256'))
'QmYtUc4iTCbbfVSDNKvtQqrfyezPPnFvE33wFmutw9PBBk'
```

The intent is to re-create the IPFS path `QmZLXzjiZU39eN8QirMZ2CGXjMLiuEkQriRu7a7FeSB4fg` using the multihashes package.

I'm able to create the same hash `QmYtUc...9PBBk` as shown in the example here:  https://github.com/multiformats/multihash#example

Comment: I went through pretty much the same process: http://0kalmi.blogspot.hu/2015/12/what-goes-into-ipfs-multihash.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IPFS uses [multihash](https://github.com/multiformats/multihash) where the format is the following:

> **base58(<varint hash function code><varint digest size in bytes><hash function output>)**

The list of hash function codes can be found in [this table](https://github.com/multiformats/multicodec/blob/master/table.csv).

Here's some pseudocode of the process using [SHA2-256](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) as the hashing function.

```
sha2-256   size  sha2-256("hello world")
0x12       0x20  0xb94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

Concatenating those three items will produce

```
1220b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

Which then you encode it to [base58](https://incoherency.co.uk/base58/)

```
QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

---

**Here's an example of how to essentially implement multihash in JavaScript:**

```js
    const crypto = require('crypto')
    const bs58 = require('bs58')
    
    const data = 'hello world'
    
    const hashFunction = Buffer.from('12', 'hex') // 0x20
    
    const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest()
    
    console.log(digest.toString('hex')) // b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
    
    const digestSize = Buffer.from(digest.byteLength.toString(16), 'hex')
    
    console.log(digestSize.toString('hex')) // 20
    
    const combined = Buffer.concat([hashFunction, digestSize, digest])
    
    console.log(combined.toString('hex')) // 1220b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
    
    const multihash = bs58.encode(combined)
    
    console.log(multihash.toString()) // QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

---

**There's a CLI you can use to generate multihashes:**

```sh
    $ go get github.com/multiformats/go-multihash/multihash
    $ echo -n "hello world" | multihash -a sha2-256
    QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

---

As @David stated, **A file in IPFS is "transformed" into a Unixfs "file", which is a representation of files in a [DAG](https://github.com/ipfs/specs/tree/master/merkledag)**. So when you use `add` to upload a file to IPFS, the data has metadata wrapper which will give you a different result when you multihash it.

For example:

```sh
    $ echo -n "hello world" | ipfs add -Q
    Qmf412jQZiuVUtdgnB36FXFX7xg5V6KEbSJ4dpQuhkLyfD
```

---

**Here's an example in Node.js of how to generate the exact same multihash as `ipfs add`:**

```js
    const Unixfs = require('ipfs-unixfs')
    const {DAGNode} = require('ipld-dag-pb')
    
    const data = Buffer.from('hello world', 'ascii')
    const unixFs = new Unixfs('file', data)
    
    DAGNode.create(unixFs.marshal(), (err, dagNode) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err)
    
      console.log(dagNode.toJSON().multihash) // Qmf412jQZiuVUtdgnB36FXFX7xg5V6KEbSJ4dpQuhkLyfD
    })
```

Comment: Is it possible to verify/check that created ipfs hash is valid? @Miguel Mota

Comment: @alper You can check the format of the varints, check against a known set of hash functions, and verify that the length matches whatever data follows. For fixed-length hash functions you can also verify that the length is "correct".

Comment: I found the function to do this on the following link: https://github.com/ipld/py-cid  @ Arthur2e5

Answer (score 2):

A file in IPFS is 'transformed' into a Unixfs file, which is a representation of files in a DAG, in your example, you are hashing directly your  multihash.txt with sha2-256, but what happens inside IPFS is:

- file gets chunked into 256KiB pieces
- each chunk goes into a DAG node inside a Unixfs protobuf https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-unixfs
- a dag is created with links to all the chunks.

Comment: If a folder has 2 different files, how will be the main folder`s hash is obtained?

Answer (score 1):

```
const { randomBytes } = require('crypto')
const multihash = require('multihashes')

const buffer = Buffer.from(randomBytes(32), 'hex')
const encoded = multihash.encode(buffer, 'sha2-256')
const hash = multihash.toB58String(encoded)
console.log(hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers are outdated. This is what worked for me:

```js
const { UnixFS } = require('ipfs-unixfs') // @4.0.3
const { DAGNode } = require('ipld-dag-pb') // @0.22.2

const data = Buffer.from("Hello World\n")
const file = new UnixFS({data})
const node = new DAGNode(file.marshal())

const link = await node.toDAGLink()
const cid = link.Hash
console.log(cid.toV0().toString())
// Qmf412jQZiuVUtdgnB36FXFX7xg5V6KEbSJ4dpQuhkLyfD
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way currently is to simply use `ipfs-http-client`. All above previous solutions in this thread don't work for me anymore.

```
import ipfsClient from "ipfs-http-client";
const ipfs = ipfsClient(IPFS_PROVIDER, "5001", { protocol: "https" });

// onlyHash: true only generates the hash and doesn't upload the file
const hash = (await ipfs.add(new Buffer(vuln), { onlyHash: true }))[0].hash
```