# Why IPFS's multihash can decode?

Tags: ipfs

I have read this stackoverflow post: 
[How to create an IPFS compatible multihash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998621/how-to-create-an-ipfs-compatible-multihash)

```
$ echo "Hello World" | ipfs add -n
$ added QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u
```

base58

```
12 - 20 - 74410577111096cd817a3faed78630f2245636beded412d3b212a2e09ba593ca
<hash-type> - <hash-length> - <hash-digest>
```

`ipfs cat`

```
$ curl "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/object/data?arg=QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u"

Hello World
```

So I was wondering how does ipfs's decoding work?

Since as far as I know, sha-256 hash function is ONE-WAY hashing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly, IPFS is a (key, value) storage service. The multihash you get from `ipfs add` command is the multihash of the value, also the key to retrieve the value from IPFS service with `ipfs get` or `ipfs object` commands.

With http api of IPFS service, `curl "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/object/data?arg=key` works exactly same as `ipfs object data` command.

So it is not about decoding the hash, it is just get the value with you key(the multihash).