# Node-less way to generate a CID that matches IPFS-Desktop CID

Tags: javascript, sha256, ipfs

I'd like to generate a CID (Content identifier) for a file in javascript without having access to an IPFS node or the internet. I've tried using [js-multihashing-async](https://github.com/multiformats/js-multihashing-async) to first hash the file and [js-cid](https://github.com/multiformats/js-cid) to generate a CID from the hash but I get a different CID than if I just add the file to [ipfs-desktop](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-desktop). It looks like the problem is an IPFS node chunks data and the CID is for the DAG that links the files' chunks. I've tried this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-only-hash) but it doesn't produce the same CID as ipfs-desktop does for the same file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998621/how-to-create-an-ipfs-compatible-multihash) question is essentially the same as mine but none of the answers give a CID that matches the ipfs-desktop-generated CID.

Comment: Given that `js-cid` is open source: have you asked why their CID does not match what `ipfs-desktop` yields over on https://github.com/multiformats/js-cid/issues? Maybe it's a bug, and you posting here instead of in the right place means it'll never get fixed. Or maybe you're just calling it with the wrong arguments, in which case the people who maintain that software are the best folks to point that out to you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know it shouldn't work just using js-cid as the CID IPFS generates is (as I understand it) a CID of the DAG for file's 256KB-sized chunks. I opened an issue in the ipfs-only-hash as this repo seems like it should give the same CID as an ipfs node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ipfs-only-hash` is the right module to use to create an IPFS CID from a file or a Buffer, without needing to start an IPFS daemon. For the same input file and the same options, it should produce the same CID.

This example is from the `ipfs-only-hash` tests, where it verifies that it hashes the same buffer to the same CID as a js-ipfs node does.

```js
test('should produce the same hash as IPFS', async t => {
  const data = Buffer.from('TEST' + Date.now())
  const ipfs = new Ipfs({ repo: path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${Date.now()}`) })

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ipfs.on('ready', resolve).on('error', reject)
  })

  const files = await ipfs.add(data)
  const hash = await Hash.of(data)

  t.is(files[0].hash, hash)
})
```

https://github.com/alanshaw/ipfs-only-hash/blob/dbb72ccfff45ffca5fbea6a7b1704222f6aa4354/test.js#L21-L33

I'm one of the maintainers of IPFS Desktop, and under the hood, that app calls `ipfs.add` on http api for the local IPFS daemon [here](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-webui/blob/0edbe8a875c9ba55ae4fa8c9e984496e6ed4dc85/src/bundles/files/actions.js#L189-L195)

When adding or hashing a file manually via the api, there are options to alter how files are chunked into blocks, how those blocks are linked together, and how the blocks are hashed. If any option values differ then the resulting hash and the CID that contains it will be different, even if the input file is the same.

You can experiment with those options and see a visualisation of the resulting DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) structure here: https://dag.ipfs.io/

For a deep dive on how IPFS chunks and hashes files you can see the author of the `ipfs-only-hash` and maintainer of `js-ipfs` explain it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5zNPwMDYGg

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of posterity, here is how to match an image's CID downloaded via fetch to the CID generated from ipfs-desktop for the same image (added as a file from the local drive). You have to remove the prefix `data:*/*;base64,` that is prepended to the image's base64string and decode the string into a buffer array. Then you get the matching CID.

```
async testHashes() {
  const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IanPhilips/jst-cids-test/master/src/23196210.jpg";
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)

    })).then(async dataUrl =>{

        const strData = dataUrl as string;
        // remove "data:*/*;base64," from dataUrl
        const endOfPrefix = strData.indexOf(",");
        const cleanStrData = strData.slice(endOfPrefix+1);
        const data = Buffer.from(cleanStrData, "base64");
        const hash = await Hash.of(data);
        console.log("fetch data CID: " + hash); // QmYHzA8euDgUpNy3fh7JRwpPwt6jCgF35YTutYkyGGyr8f
    });

  console.log("ipfs-desktop CID: QmYHzA8euDgUpNy3fh7JRwpPwt6jCgF35YTutYkyGGyr8f");
}
```